# Typescript - generic rest parameter with constraints

Tags: typescript

I have the following type for a "Validator Function":

```
type Validator<V, P extends {} | void = void> = (value: V, props: P) => string | undefined
```

where it takes in a value, and optionally some additional information as an object and returns an error message or undefined.

Now I want to create a function which takes multiple of these "Validator Function" and returns a single one like so:

```
const validate = merge(
  (value: string | number) => !Boolean(value) ? 'Required Error' : undefined
  (value: string, props: { minLength: number }) => value < minLength ? 'Min Length Error' : undefined
  (value: string, props: { maxLength: number }) => value > maxLength ? 'Max Length Error' : undefined
)

const result = validate('1234567', { minLength: 1, maxLength: 6 }) // => 'Max Length Error'
```

I have the implementation but I cannot quite seem to get the typing right. I have the following:

```
function merge<T extends Validator<any, any>[]>(...fns: T): T extends Validator<infer V, infer R>[] ? Validator<V, R> : never {
  // Implementation
}
```

And this produces the correct return value but the arguments are not strongly typed since I have <any, any>. Is there a way to do this with the constraints, ensuring all V values and the same type and all P values extends {})? Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand the point of creating the `merge` function, couldn't you just use function overloading instead?